# Navigation Fade in HTML with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fade in and fade out my navigation on my website with plain Javascript. I can't find anything on google.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbarTitel">

        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="navbarItems">
            <ul class="navbarList">
                <li class="navbarListItem"><a href="#HeroContainer"> Home </a></li>
                <li class="navbarListItem"><a href="#AboutMe"> über mich </a></li>
                <li class="navbarListItem"><a href="#"> Meine Referenzen </a></li>
                <li class="navbarListItem"><a href="#Contact"> Kontakt </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
position: fixed;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
line-height: 50px;
z-index: 1;
}

.navbarScroller {
background-color: #111111;
}
```

JS: (what I tried)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var navigation = document.querySelector('#menu')

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(this.scrollY < 200) {
        navigation.classList.toggle('navbarScroller')
    }})

})
```

I want to fade in black background of navigation if I scroll down 50px or something

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does the class toggle fire?

Comment: My problem is... i don't know how to do javascript... i don't know if that what i wrote is javascript 

Comment: But i know.. if i clear the if then it works but it's like a onscroll function